# Rhino mocks sub method always returns null

Tags: .net, rhino-mocks

here is my unit test code:

```
var aFake = new A(false);
var bFake = new B(aFake);
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IC>();
mock.Stub(x => x.GetTypeB()).Return(bFake);
```

And when it gets called the method GetTypeB always returns null instead of bFake.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
The IC type is injected into constructor of the tested class using DI.

I noticed that when the mock is created and when it's getting called it has different MockedObjectInstances:

After GenerateMock
{Castle.Proxies.ICe6556c917a514365ba77dcf8feaa9f93}

After it's called:
{Castle.Proxies.IC20f29ed85d9a4b8381f380cccd1939fc}

Comment: Not enough details provided. where/how is the mock injected? what is the SUT (system under test)? Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem so we can better assist you.

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: Show the code for the tested class with how it uses the dependency

Comment: I was wrong: the project I'm working with uses DI to inject dependencies, but in this case it uses some Builders and Reflection. I had to inject this mock into parameters list wich is used by reflection to create new instance of the tested class. @Nkosi, thanks a lot for putting me into right direction :)